# Is there a program in wxpython that gives the user the option to draw any shape he wants

Tags: wxpython

Is there a wxpython program that let the user draw any kind of
shapes, similarly to paint program in windows. I need just few simple
features:
1) drawing with the mouse like a pencil
2) typing text
3) erasing with the mouse.

If there is a program that has these features I will be glad to know,
if not any tips on how to create such a program will help.

Thanks,
 Yuval

Answer (score 0):

This sample could be a good starting point for you: https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/tree/master/samples/doodle